After apt-get upgrade 24.04 LTS kernel don’t detect bluetooth
My Lenovo Legion Pro 5 16ARX8 24.04 LTS laptop don’t detect bluetooth anymore after upgrading gnome and other packages (cuda-driver is 560 from nvidia and X11). Kernel is 6.8.0-40.

gdm3 don’t allow typing password unless systemctl restart gdm3 is used to restart gdm3.

linux kernel don’t detect bluetooth at all. I can modprobe btusb and systemctl restart bluetooth to get bluetoothd running but still there is no bluetooth. (No /sys/dev/bluetooth/, no hci0 etc). rfkill shows ideapad_bluetooth but other commands don’t show bluetooth.


How to get bluetooth running again?

Upgrade paths will open after 24.04.1 is released, which will take several months. Don't force upgrade. Doing a forced upgrade gave you 24.04.0 you should have waited till the system prompted you to upgrade to 24.04.1

Can you edit the question to include results from terminal for lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'

I had a similar problem with the same kernel but on 22.04 LTS. My JBL Charge 3 stopped working, but other devices are still working properly.
